# String Concatenation: Putting large chuck of text in Python code

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Suppose I have a large chunk of text, say

> The third and final rotation of Himalayan Pilgrimage explores the
>   theme of Sacred Space with a pair of magnificent large mandala
>   paintings, two-dimensional representations of a three-dimensional
>   architectural space where a specific deity resides. Dating to the
>   fourteenth and sixteenth centuries, these paintings represent, in
>   vivid colors, a cosmology of the deity Hevajra. Several other
>   paintings on view depict historic teachers of various Tibetan orders.

In Java I can write it as

```
"The third and final rotation of Himalayan Pilgrimage explores "
+ "the theme of Sacred Space with a pair of magnificent large "
+ "mandala paintings, two-dimensional representations of a "
+ "three-dimensional architectural space where a specific "
+ "deity resides. Dating to the fourteenth and sixteenth "
+ "centuries, these paintings represent, in vivid colors, "
+ "a cosmology of the deity Hevajra. Several other paintings"
+ " on view depict historic teachers of various Tibetan orders."
```

In Python, however, if I do the same, I get complaints about the plus signs `+`. If instead I use `'''` I get a bunch of leading white spaces due to indentation (indentation so the code is easy to read).

Does anyone know the solution to this problem: how to paste a big chuck of text into Python code without incurring white spaces?

The answer I am looking for is not: put the whole text on one line

Again, I need to add text that span more than one line without incurring additional white space.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you use the triple quote string you do not *have* to indent:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def somemethod(self):
        return '''\
This text
does not need to be indented
at all.
In this text, newlines are preserved.
'''
        # but do continue the next line at the right indentation.
```

You can also join strings automatically by using parenthesis:

```
foo = (
    "this text will be "
    "joined into one long string. "
    "Note that I don't need to concatenate these "
    "explictly. No newlines are included\n"
    "unless you insert them explicitly."
)
```

because python will concatenate consecutive strings in one expression together automatically (see [*String literal concatenation*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation)).

You are still free to use `+` signs to concatenate the strings explicitly, but do use parenthesis to make it one expression:

```
foo = (
    "this text will be " +
    "joined into one long string. " + 
    "It is concatenated " +
    "explictly using the `+` operator."
)
```

The alternative would be to use a backslash before the end of the line:

```
foo = "This is not " \
    "recommended"
```

but I find using parentheses and string literal concatenation to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this, when you have multiple strings with nothing but whitespace between them, the compiler creates a single string from them, as already said.  You can also use `\` to escape the end of line, like so.

```
SomeText="Something" \
         "Something else"
```

or

```
SomeText="Something" + \
         "Something else"
```

The downside to this is you must remember the `\` on every line.  As a general rule, using `+` to join many strings together is a bad idea, because it makes a copy of the string for every `+` it finds, because strings are immutable, which makes it take a long time.  Instead consider using `str.join`, like this.

```
SomeText="\n".join(["Something",
                  "Something else",
                  "Last Item"])
```

Note that this has the added advantage that you can replace the `" "` with some other separator depending on what you are doing (newline or no character).

Comment: You are using `str.join()` rather unconventionally; it'll work, but *normally* you call that with `'\n'.join(sequence_of_strings)` instead.

Comment: I am, normally when using `str.join`, I am using it with an empty string, often within a function call, and I find `someFunction(''.join(someList))` to be deceptive to read at a glance, it is easy to mistake it for `someFunction('',join(someList))`, so I found calling str.join explicitly more clear.  Since this isn't an empty string, it should be written as you put it.

Answer (score 0):

[`textwrap.dedent`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) will clean up those leading spaces, without messing up your source indentation.